FLC100 Flux Gate: How does the reference voltage work?
I am using a set of six Stefan Mayer FLC100 flux gate magnetometers to measure a magnetic field along 3 axes. 
My current understanding of how to use these is that you take the differential measurement between the OUTPUT+ and OUTPUT- where the OUTPUT- is a reference voltage of 2.5V (hopefully correct). My question is, why is a reference voltage required? And also, when I view the output from the OUPUT- it's closer to 1.9V subject to some variation. I also took data from both outputs over the course of 8 hours, and see variations in both:

Shouldn't a reference voltage remain constant? Why is it not 2.5V? I thought maybe because a differential measurement would negate any variations if trending in same direction, but outputs trend differently. I don't have much experience with electronics so any help is much appreciated.


What are the measurements "OUT+" - "OUT-" .vs. time?

The field is found by multiplying OUT+ - OUT- by 0.5 (convert voltage to Gauss as specified in the data sheet), so the field graph shows the general shape

@Antonio51 Have included the differential in the plots now

The magnitude of Earth's magnetic field at its surface ranges from 25 to 65 μT. You should measure adding +/- 50 uT to verify if it does.
